# About to_bytes() method of int type

Tags: python, byte

I have a question about `to_bytes` method of `int` type in Python.

Say, `a = 100`.

Why is `a.to_bytes(2, "big")` not `b"\x00\x64"` but `b"\x00d"`?

Seems to me that `b"\x00d"` is not even 2 bytes.

Comment: `ord('d')` *is* `100` — in other words, it's due to the (admittedly odd) way Python prints byte strings.

Comment: `b"\x00d"` is treated as byte `\x00` and byte `d` - so you have 2 bytes. If byte's value is correct char's code then it displays char instead of its code - to make it more readable beacause it may have some readable text. And `chr(0x64)` gives `d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b"\x00d"` means 2 bytes: `\x00` and `d` but for values which are correct char codes (which are `"printable"`) Python displays chars instead of codes. It makes it more readable when it may have readable text.

And `chr(0x64)` gives `d`

But if you use `.hex()` then you can get string `0064`, and with `.hex(":")` you can get `00:64` (but it can't use `.hex("\\x")`)

If you want only codes `\x...` then you may have to convert it to string on your own (for example using `for`-loop and `f-string`)

```
a = 100
b = a.to_bytes(2, "big")

print('chr(0x64) :', chr(0x64))
print('b         :', b)
print('b.hex()   :', b.hex())
print('b.hex(":"):', b.hex(':'))

# ------------------------------------

items = []

for value in b:
    items.append( f'\\x{value:02x}' )

text = "".join(items)

print('text:', text)

# shorter
print('text:', "".join(f'\\x{q:02x}' for q in b) )
```

Result:

```
chr(0x64) : d
b         : b'\x00d'
b.hex()   : 0064
b.hex(":"): 00:64

text: \x00\x64
text: \x00\x64
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  Now I have understood that this representation makes bytes more  readable.